# Apache arrow - read serialized VectorSchemaRoot to C++

Tags: apache-arrow

I have a Java library that is writing an Arrow Table to a `VectorSchemaRoot` object in memory. Those serailized bytes are available to me in a `std::string` object in C++. How do I de-serialize and read the data?

Java:

```
try (final ArrowStreamWriter arrowStreamWriter
         = new ArrowStreamWriter(vectorSchemaRoot, provider, outputStream)) {
    arrowStreamWriter.start();
    arrowStreamWriter.writeBatch();
    arrowStreamWriter.end();
    return buffer.byteArray();
}
```

C++

```
std::string bytes;
???
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've writen a RecordBatch, I think you can read it back this way:

```
#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <arrow/ipc/writer.h>
#include <arrow/io/memory.h>

// ...

  std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::BufferReader> bufferReader = std::make_shared<arrow::io::BufferReader>(bytes);
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::ipc::RecordBatchStreamReader> reader = arrow::ipc::RecordBatchStreamReader::Open(bufferReader.get()).ValueOrDie();
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatch> recordBatchBack =  reader->Next().ValueOrDie();
  std::cout << recordBatchBack->num_rows() << std::endl;
```

Here's an end to end test in c++:

```
#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <arrow/ipc/writer.h>
#include <arrow/ipc/reader.h>
#include <arrow/io/memory.h>


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(RecordBatchStreamReaderTest) {
  arrow::Int32Builder builder;
  builder.Append(1);
  builder.Append(2);
  builder.Append(3);

  auto schema = arrow::schema({arrow::field("hello", arrow::int32())});
  auto structArray = arrow::StructArray::Make({builder.Finish().ValueOrDie()}, {"hello"}).ValueOrDie();
  auto recordBatch = arrow::RecordBatch::FromStructArray(structArray).ValueOrDie();
  auto outputStream = arrow::io::BufferOutputStream::Create().ValueOrDie();

  auto writer = arrow::ipc::MakeStreamWriter(outputStream.get(), schema).ValueOrDie();

  writer->WriteRecordBatch(*recordBatch);
  writer->Close();
  auto buffer = outputStream->Finish().ValueOrDie();
  std::string bytes = buffer->ToString();

  std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::BufferReader> bufferReader = std::make_shared<arrow::io::BufferReader>(bytes);
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::ipc::RecordBatchStreamReader> reader = arrow::ipc::RecordBatchStreamReader::Open(bufferReader.get()).ValueOrDie();
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatch> recordBatchBack =  reader->Next().ValueOrDie();
  std::cout << recordBatchBack->num_rows() << std::endl;

}
```